# XCode 5.1 Assets Catalog Size

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog, xcasset

I created an asset catalog for my ios cordova app. The .xcassets folder seems to be working, however I cannot delete the image files from my resources folder. This is causing my app to be 14.5 MB in size (which seems like a lot). How can I have my images only a single location?

[image]

I have the images in the Resource folder and in Images-2.xcassets ( I think)

Comment: 14.5 MB isn't that big, especially if you have retina graphics. What do you mean by "cannot delete the image files from my resources folder"?

Comment: Oops. I took a screen shot and forgot to post it. I do have all my retina graphics, however before I created the assets catalog my app size was at ~7 MB. ( I had to create the assets catalog because I could not get the launch image on 4 inch iphones to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all the images and remake the asset catalogue and directly add images to your asset catalogue it will copy all the images to your project need not to add explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! This led me to my problem. When I deleted the images from my resource folder, it did not delete the reference. So the compiler was still trying to find those images in that folder. Once I deleted the references I was able to use the asset catalogue without having any images within my resource folder.